# Как правильно сделать второстепенное диалоговое окно c функционалом на python через модуль tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite3, ttk

Мне нужно сделать курсовую работу, которая заключается в том что бы создать 8 таблиц для БД "Зоомагазин", у меня есть таблицы PetShop - главное диалоговое окно при запуске. Можно добавить значение, удалить, изменить, найти и обновить таблицу. А также 7 второстепенных таблиц, которые можно открыть в дополнительных диалоговых окнах по нажатию отведенной кнопки (приложу скрины к этому). Столкнулся с проблемой что, мол вместо того что бы открывалось такое же диалоговое окно (но без перехода на другие таблицы по кнопкам, только CRUD функционал), у меня выдает след. ошибку: [image]

[Код по этой ссылке](https://github.com/alreadydeadinside/ZooShopDB-CourseWork/blob/main/main.py)

Вот основное диалоговое окно:
[image]
Вот дополнительное, с ошибкой:
[image]

Comment: Мне кажется, что у Вас что-то не то с версиями пакетов. Я пытался выполнить ошибочную строку у себя на питоне 3.9.1 и он ругался не на сам параметр *bg*, а на формат записи кода цвета. Вот такой оператор у меня отработал нормально: *toolbar = ttk.Frame(bg='Red', bd=2)*

Comment: Приведите в самом вопросе [минимальный код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), с которым возникает проблема. В коде по ссылке нет упоминаний ttk.Frame, на который у вас указывает ошибка.